# Memory usage issue for large numpy arrays within the for loop & arithmetic operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am quite new to python. I have a implicit time integration for loop, that is, next step depends on the previous step. Basically, I am trying to solve the time integration for all different cases by utilizing broadcast feature of numpy arrays without utilizing more for loops. Thus, I have large arrays.

The loop takes short time to run (2.5s) but while conducting the operations within the for loops my RAM (8 GB) reaches nearly its capacity. Therefore, there is a memory usage issue I am trying to overcome.

```
ndata = 9624
u.shape = (3, 9624, 11, 3, 1000)
p.shape = (9624, 11, 1, 1000)
a1.shape = (11, 3, 1000)
a2.shape = (11, 3, 1000)
a3.shape = (11, 3, 1000)
p_star.shape = (11, 3, 1000)
delta_t.shape =(11, 1, 1)
k_star.shape =(11, 3, 1000)

for i in range(0,ndata-1):
    p_star = p[i+1] + a1 * u[0,i] + a2 * u[1,i] + a3 * u[2,i]
    u[0,i+1] = p_star / k_star
    u[1,i+1] = gama * (u[0,i+1]-u[0,i]) / (beta * delta_t) + u[1,i] * (1 - gama/beta) + delta_t * u[2,i] * (1 - gama/(2*beta))
    u[2,i+1] = (u[0,i+1]-u[0,i]) / (beta * (delta_t ** 2)) - u[1,i] / (beta * delta_t) - u[2,i] * ((1 / (2*beta)) - 1)
```

[You can see memory usage in the loop here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFUpB.jpg)

During the aritmatic operations, the temporary copies of the arrays are created and assigned. I think main issue here is creation the copies of the arrays. To overcome this issue, arithmatic operations should be conducted in-place.

To conduct these operations, as far as I know, optional argument *out=* of numpy ufuncs should be defined or += -= *= /= should be used. For example, *[numpy.sum(a1,a2, out=a1)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)*.

But in order to conduct above mentioned operations in in-place fashion I have to define a lot of auxiliary (or buffer) variables.
My question is what is the optimal way to decrease this memory usage. I believe that, in python, there must be a elegant way to do these type of arithmetic operations in-place.

I am open to other suggestions as well.

```
buff1 = np.zeros_like(u[0,0])
buff2 = np.zeros_like(u[0,0])
buff3 = np.zeros_like(u[0,0])
buff4 = np.zeros_like(u[0,0])
for i in range(0,ndata-1):
    # first line
    np.multiply(a1, u[0,i], out = buff1);
    np.multiply(a2, u[1,i], out = buff2);
    np.multiply(a3, u[2,i], out = buff3);
    buff1 += p[i+1];
    buff1 += buff2;
    buff1 += buff3;
    #second line
    np.divide(buff1, k_star, out = u[0,i+1])
    #third line
    np.subtract(u[0,i+1], u[0,i], out = buff1);
    buff1 *= gama
    buff1 /= beta
    buff1 /= delta_t
    np.divide(gama,beta, out = buff2)
    np.subtract(1, buff2, out=buff2)
    np.multiply(u[1,i], buff2, out=buff2)
    np.multiply(2, beta, out = buff3)
    np.divide(gama, buff3, out = buff3)
    np.subtract(1, buff3, out = buff3)
    np.multiply(u[2,i], buff3, out = buff3)
    np.multiply(delta_t, buff3, out = buff3)
    np.add(buff1, buff2, out = u[1,i+1])
    np.add(buff3, u[1,i+1], out = u[1,i+1])
    #last line goes like that
```

Comment: Your `u` array has almost a billion elements on its own. Depending on the dtype, that array alone could fill your RAM. You are severely pushing the limits of your hardware.

Comment: It doesn't look like you really need to store all of `u` in memory at once. Each time step only depends on the previous time step. You don't need to store 9624 time steps' worth of data at the same time.

Comment: Yes it is very large but after the for loop RAM usage decreases to normal level (~1-1.5 GB) and the variables including u preserves. So that is why I am pointing to the operations within the loop for memory usage.

Comment: I will use data in u for the further calculations. Unfortunately, all 9624 time steps are needed

Comment: There's something important you're not telling us. Any temporaries created in the loop are tiny in comparison to `u` itself. They aren't anywhere near big enough to cause the memory effects you say you're seeing. Only `u` and `p` themselves are anywhere near large enough to cause problems.

Comment: Ah. You're using that memory profiler thing. Pretty much every time I've seen anyone post output from it, it's been complete garbage. Look at the "Increment" column, for example - it says that memory usage *dropped* by over **16 terabytes** on most of the lines.

Comment: I have no idea how the output of that thing is supposed to be interpreted. The entire conceptual model doesn't make any sense. The "Mem usage" column is documented as the interpreter's memory usage after executing a given line, but that whole idea is nonsense when the line is in a loop and it gets executed over and over. I suspect it may not be intended to support loops at all, but the documentation doesn't mention loop one way or another.

Comment: I guess the existence of the "Occurences" column suggests there was probably an intent to do something meaningful with loops at some point. Still, I recommend uninstalling `memory_profiler` and ignoring anything it ever told you about memory usage.

Comment: Have you tried using a sparse matrix?

Comment: Unfortunately, the arrays are dense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually the size of the arrays p and u. Combined, they are made of roughly a billion floats, each represented with 64 bits. Or, in total, 8 GBs. I am afraid that there is not much that you can do about it if you need to keep all 9264 time steps -- of course the situation changes if you can keep only the two last time steps.